# Trying to get property of non-object CodeIgniter frame work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when i var dump `$userData` it will return

> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["title"]=> string(3) "Mrs" ["name"]=> string(6) "Devaka"
>   ["username"]=> string(6) "Dabare" ["email"]=> string(23)
>   "devakadabare1@gmail.com" ["contactnum"]=> string(10) "0750548469"
>   ["user_address"]=> string(40) "260/B,Station Road, Angulana, Moratuwa"
>   ["district"]=> string(7) "Colombo" ["password"]=> string(8) "12345679"
>   ["buyer"]=> string(1) "1" ["seller"]=> string(1) "0" } }

but when i echo `$userData->name`

it will gives  error

> Trying to get property of non-object

**user.php controller**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model','',true);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['userData'] = $this->User_model->getUser();
        //$data['userEditData'] = $result[0];
        $this->load->view('profile/index', $data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
class User_model extends CI_model{

     public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getUser(){
        $query = $this->db->where(array('id'=>1))
            ->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only single result(row) from database. Use `$query->row();` instead of `$query->result();`

So change your model as below then try your code:

```
public function getUser(){
        $query = $this->db->where(array('id'=>1))
            ->get('users');
        return $query->row();
    }
```